# How do get parameter without name in python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, getopt

I am trying to write a python script which accepts optional input parameters plus an input file:

`./script --lines 1 file.txt`

should take `1` for the number of lines (`--lines`) and then take `file.txt` as an input file. However, `getopt` does not even see "file.txt" since it does not have a parameter name in front of it.

How can I get the filename? I already considered using `sys.arv[-1]`, but this means when I run:

`./script --lines 1`

then `1` will be taken as the input filename. My script will then throw an error (if no file named `1` exists):

`error: file '1' no found`

This works, but is not a great solution. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Use the `argparse` module...

Comment: One possible workaround is to check if sys.argv[-1] is a valid file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely use `argparse` -- It's included in python2.7+ and can easily be installed for older versions:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--lines', type=int, default=0, help='number of lines')
parser.add_argument('file', help='name of file')
namespace = parser.parse_args()
print namespace.lines
print namespace.file
```

Comment: Replacing getopt with ArgumentParser reduced my code size by a few dozen lines. This is the way to go.

Comment: @pap42 -- Hearing that makes me very happy.  I suppose this is the reason that the python team went from `getopt` -> `optparser` -> `argparse`...

Answer (score 3):

In a call to `getopts`:

```
opts, args = getopts(...)
```

the second element is a list of arguments not recognized by `getopts`. In your example, it will be a list containing the single item 'file.txt'.